# How to replace a list of longer column names with small names in a dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, data-analysis

- I have a list of column names which are too lengthy that it messes the code. I want to replace that list of column names with a list shorter name.
- Here's an example of columns:

```
    non_multi_choice = ["what_is_the_highest_level_of_formal_education_that_you_have_attained_or_plan_to_attain_within_the_next_2_years",
          "select_the_title_most_similar_to_your_current_role_or_most_recent_title_if_retired_selected_choice",
          "in_what_industry_is_your_current_employer_contract_or_your_most_recent_employer_if_retired_selected_choice",
          "how_many_years_of_experience_do_you_have_in_your_current_role",
          "what_is_your_current_yearly_compensation_approximate_usd",
          "does_your_current_employer_incorporate_machine_learning_methods_into_their_business",
          "of_the_choices_that_you_selected_in_the_previous_question_which_ml_library_have_you_used_the_most_selected_choice",
          "approximately_what_percent_of_your_time_at_work_or_school_is_spent_actively_coding"]
```

```
    shorter_names = ["highest_level_of_formal_education",
      "job_title",
      "current_industry",
      "years_of_experience",
      "yearly_compensation",
      "does_your_current_employer_incorporate_machine_learning_methods_into_their_business",
      "which_ml_library_have_you_used_the_most_selected_choice",
      "what_percent_of_your_time_at_work_is_spent_actively_coding"]
```

- I want to replace each name in the first list with the names in second list corresponding to it.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Why don't you just use `shorter_names`? Or if you must, copy the *reference*  `non_multi_choice = shorter_names`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(non_multi_choice):
  non_multi_choice[index] = shorter_names[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are encompassing all the column names then :

```
df.columns = shorter_names
```

If not

```
df.rename(columns = {old:new for old, new in zip(non_multi_choice, shorter_names})
```